# how to ignore error records while updating the entries when error inner exception for details

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How can I ignore writing of records giving error while updating the entities.

[ERROR DISPLAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1CFd.png)

```
   private void btn_salary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sg.HasRows(lib.tbl_pay) == true && chkShowOnly.Checked == false)
        {
            lib.ShowMessage(lib.tbl_pay + " has data can not import");
            return;
        }
        sql = "SELECT * FROM PAY WHERE BankAc IS NOT null";
        q1 = new DBFHelper(txt_olddir.Text).FillDataTable(sql);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = q1;
        if (chkShowOnly.Checked == true) return;
        DateTime xdate = sg.ServerDate;
        for (int x = 0; x < q1.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            PAY q11 = new PAY
            {

                BANKAC = sg.AsString(q1.Rows[x]["BankAc"]),
                MDATE = sg.AsDate(q1.Rows[x]["MDATE"].ToString()),
                BYEAR = sg.AsDate(q1.Rows[x]["MDATE"].ToString()).Year,
                BMONTH = sg.AsDate(q1.Rows[x]["MDATE"].ToString()).Month,
                PERPAY = q1.AsDecimal("PERPAY", x),
                BASIC = q1.AsDecimal("PERPAY", x),
                DARATE = q1.AsDecimal("DA", x),
                NEWDA = q1.AsDecimal("NEWDA",x),
                ADNDA = q1.AsDecimal ("ADNDA",x),
                HRA = q1.AsDecimal ("HRA",x),
                ENTREL = q1.AsDecimal("ENTREL",x),
                EXTRA = q1.AsDecimal("EXTRA",x),
                INSKNP = q1.AsDecimal("INSGKP",x),
                MEDI = q1.AsDecimal("MEDI",x),
                RD = q1.AsDecimal("RD",x),
                GPF = q1.AsDecimal("GPF",x),
                GPFLOAN= q1.AsDecimal("GPFLOAN",x),
                CPF = q1.AsDecimal("CPF",x),
                CPFLOAN = q1.AsDecimal("CPFLOAN",x),
                LICPRE = q1.AsDecimal("LICPRE",x),
                LICLOAN = q1.AsDecimal("LICLOAN",x),
                ITAX = q1.AsDecimal("ITAX",x),
                JSBLOAN = q1.AsDecimal("JSBLOAN",x),
                NSBLOAN = q1.AsDecimal("NSBLOAN",x),
                STEMP = q1.AsDecimal("STEMP",x),
                PROFUND = q1.AsDecimal("PROFUND",x),
                TYPE_ATX = q1.AsString("TYPE",x),
                GRADE = q1.AsString("GRADE",x),
                TFUND = q1.AsDecimal("TFUND",x),
                GFUND = q1.AsDecimal("GFUND",x),
                OBCLOAN = q1.AsDecimal("OBCLOAN",x),
                OTH1_LOAN = q1.AsDecimal("OTH1_LOAN",x),
                OTH2_LOAN = q1.AsDecimal("OTH2_LOAN",x),
                BSTGBANK = q1.AsDecimal("BSTGBANK",x),
                EARNING = q1.AsDecimal("EARNING",x),
                TOTDED = q1.AsDecimal("TOTDED",x),
                NETPAY = q1.AsDecimal("NETPAY",x),
                CITYALW = q1.AsDecimal("CITYALW",x),
                user_code = lib.user_code,
                modi_dt = xdate
            };
            g1.PAYs.Add(q11);
            lbl_counter.Text = x.ToString() + " Records Inserted";
            Application.DoEvents();
        }



        try
        {
            g1.SaveChanges();
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string emsg = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                emsg = emsg + ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
                 
            if (ex.InnerException.InnerException != null)
            {
                emsg = emsg + ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
            }
                 
            if (ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException != null)
            {
                emsg = emsg + ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
            }
               
            lib.ShowMessage(emsg);
        }
     
        lib.ShowMessage("Done..");
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to insert duplicate value for the primary key columns... that's why you are getting this error..

Comment: Yes that's true. It's a loop of more than 10000 records and i want to save it once. not one by one. Ignoring record which has primary key duplication. say out of 10000 records may be 4-5 records has problem can I ignore them while g1.SaveChanges();

Comment: You are selecting all the rows from the PAY table and then try to insert the same records back to the same table, only thing you are changing is `user_code` and `modi_dt`. Why? Why don't you retrieve entities from `g.PAYs` and loop thru them, modify only necessary properties and save them back... that will trigger UPDATE query and it will throw this error.

Comment: No I am reading record from PAY.DBF (dbase ODBC)  which is DBASE table and writing record in PAY SQL Server Table.  PAY.DBF is having lot of records from 1991 to 2019. All record I have to migrate into SQL Server PAY Table. And it is repeatable task so I am not inserting one by one record because that will be much slower  if record is more than 4-5 lacs it will take hours to insert. I am not using migration tools because it is multiple location process. What i want to know  Is there any way to ignore records which is having error in insert or update when execute dbcontext.SaveChanges() method

Comment: You might want to use some different approach then inserting directly in the table. EF does not support skipping error when executing multiple changes in one operations. You can create another able in SQL server with the same Schema as Pay table but without any primary keys. Insert the data from DBase to that table and then run SQL query to insert from that table to PAY table by using WHERE Clause to exclude the rows which already present in the PAY table...

Comment: Once INSERT operation is completed, you can empty the table and populate new rows from another DBASE able and execute INSERT query again and so on...

Comment: I added IDENTITTY field part of primary key to avoid primary key error and then deleted duplicate records and re created primary key. Thanks @ChetanRanpariya